# Assign variable inside a method

Tags: java

All objetcs (p1, p2 buyer, seller) are from the same class and initially buyer and seller objects are null. Based on the type of the document I need assign p1 and p2 to either seller or buyer.

```
Class EmailSenderUtil{
public void sendPendingActionEmail(Document Type, PartyType p1, PartyType p2){
  PartyType buyer = null;
  PartyType seller = null;
  /// some other computations

  else if(documentType.equals(DocumentType.REQUESTFORQUOTATION)) {
      assignInitiatorAsBuyer(p1, p2, buyer, seller);
     // set some other variable unique to this type
  }
}

private void assignInitiatorAsBuyer(PartyType p1, PartyType p2, PartyType buyer, PartyType seller) {
        buyer = p1;
        seller = p2;
    }
private void assignInitiatorAsSeller(PartyType p1, PartyType p2, PartyType buyer, PartyType seller) {
        buyer = p2;
        seller = p1;
    }
}
```

I can assign these variables in 2 lines but as the else if conditions are alot(10) inorder to reduce the redundancy I moved this assignment inside a method. But as Java is pass by value the assignments are not reflected to the parent method.

Would be much obliged If I could know is there any elegant way to perform this operation rather than copying the same assignment several times.

Comment: Don't pass buyer and seller as argument. Use `this.buyer` and `this.seller`in your methods.

Comment: Where are these methods? Assigning to instance variables (`this.buyer`) instead of local variables is not an option?

Comment: Java passes by value. There is no way to directly pass by reference. You would need to wrap your variables in a class, pass that class and set the values inside of the wrapper.

Comment: Are any of the four objects class variables in the class where you want to add the methods?

Comment: I have updated the question. All the methods are defined inside a util class. Thanks for the answers, ill be able to use the this. approach as well.

Answer (score 2):

After the edits provided in the question, i think we can now go with the approach where we can remove buyer and seller from the method, and use this.buyer=p1

```
Class EmailSenderUtil{
   PartyType buyer = null;
   PartyType seller = null;
    public void sendPendingActionEmail(Document Type, PartyType p1, PartyType p2){
 // .....
 // rest of the code

else if(documentType.equals(DocumentType.REQUESTFORQUOTATION)) {
    assignInitiatorAsBuyer(p1, p2, buyer, seller);
  }
}

private void assignInitiatorAsBuyer(PartyType p1, PartyType p2) {
    this.buyer = p1;
    this.seller = p2;
}
private void assignInitiatorAsSeller(PartyType p1, PartyType p2) {
    this.buyer = p2;
    this.seller = p1;
}
```

Comment: Editing the code. i thought these 2 were instance variables, as in my edited answer

Comment: yeah.. i saw that.. that is why i changed my code.. my code is only valid if the 2 variables are instance variables, as in my code.

Comment: In the question, the methods are not static, but in case they are, I can think of an alternative approach where in we can make the function return buyer and seller (both, like as an object or a list), and they can be received in the else if block when calling the function. I will update the code for this also in some time.

Comment: I now spotted in a comment from OP that `this` is OK so no need to update the question anymore. Sorry for all the noice :)

Answer (score 0):

If the methods are already present in `PartyType` use these:

```
else if(documentType.equals(DocumentType.REQUESTFORQUOTATION)) {
      assignInitiatorAsBuyer();
 // set some other variable unique to this type
}

private void assignInitiatorAsBuyer() {
        this.buyer = this.p1;
        this.seller = this.p2;
}
private void assignInitiatorAsSeller() {
        this.buyer = this.p2;
        this.seller = this.p1;
}
```

Or if it's used in other class use like this:

```
else if(documentType.equals(DocumentType.REQUESTFORQUOTATION)) {
      assignInitiatorAsBuyer(partyTypeObj);
 // set some other variable unique to this type
}

private void assignInitiatorAsBuyer(PartyTypeObjects partyTypeObj) {
        partyTypeObj.buyer = partyTypeObj.p1;
        partyTypeObj.seller = partyTypeObj.p2;
}
private void assignInitiatorAsSeller(PartyTypeObjects partyTypeObj) {
        partyTypeObj.buyer = partyTypeObj.p2;
        partyTypeObj.seller = partyTypeObj.p1;
}
```

Comment: In 2nd approach, I think we have p1, p2, buyer and seller are objects of type PartyType. They are not the members of the class Partytype, so how can we write partyType.p1, partyType.seller.

Comment: Thanks!! so now I assumed that some class like `partyTypeObjects` holds p1, p2, buyer, seller and we can use this object to achieve the work, because according to the question: All objects (p1, p2 buyer, seller) are from the same class and initially buyer and seller objects are null.

Comment: Also, with the current changes made in the code in the question, the 1st approach will also get impacted, as it contains only buyer and seller as instance members.